# Cypress-Cucumber report shows error on first attempt of szenario. How to configure that behavior?

Tags: testing, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, test-reporting

for our Angular applications we are using cypress in combination with the powerful cucumber-preprocessor by badeball.
https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

We also use the multiple-cucumber-html-reporter to generate reports
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter

All of that works very well together and we only have one problems:

**Retries**

Whenever a Szenario fails the first time, the report shows it as an error, even tho that was just the first attempt. The second attempt was successful and therefor it should not be marked as failed in the report. This doesnt happen that often and we make sure to keep our tests robust. However one flaky test should not ruin a report like that.

Is there any way to configure a different behavior?

I was not able to find anything inside the documentations of the preprocessor. There were also no issues.